# How do I configure multiple Kibana modules in metricbeat?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, monitoring, metricbeat

I am setting up a dedicated ES cluster for monitoring a production clusted as per official ES documentation. I'm able to get the metrics of ES, and now am trying to get the metrics of the two instances of production Kibana that we have.

Going by the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-module-kibana.html#_example_configuration_35), this is what is to be configured in modules.d of metricbeat.

```
metricbeat.modules:
- module: kibana
  metricsets: ["status"]
  period: 10s
  hosts: ["localhost:5601"]
  basepath: ""
  enabled: true
```

We have two instances of Kibana that independently connect to the cluster, and are not load balanced. They have separate base paths:

Eg:
Kibana-01: http://kibana-01:5601/ui/01
Kibana-02: http://kibana-02:5601/ui/02

I'm able to get a single kibana instance to be monitored in ES, but how do I handle them both?

The official docs don't mention a mechanism to add multiple base paths, or modules for that matter. How do I go about configuring this?

Comment: Hey, Can you try adding multiple hosts?
```hosts: ["http://kibana1:5601", "http://kibana2:5601"]```

Comment: @Musab I think the issue is `basepath`, not `hosts`

Comment: Yes the issue is with base path